# Applescript+Bash: Script works in the Applescript editor but not using osascript

Tags: bash, applescript

I have this bash function that runs some Applescript. If I run the Applescript part in the Applescript Editor or in Textmate, it works fine, but on the command line, the function fails...

```
wtf() {
  osascript - <<EOF
  tell application "iTerm"
      tell current terminal
          launch session "Railscasts"
          tell the last session
              write text 'echo -ne "\\e]1;$account\\a"'
          end tell
      end tell
  end tell
EOF
}
```

And the error is:

```
190:191: syntax error: Expected expression but found unknown token. (-2741)
```

I know (think) that the problem is with the first bash escape sequence on this line:

```
write text 'echo -ne "\\e]1;$account\\a"'
                      ^
```

But I don't know why it fails... Any ideas on why this doesn't work please?

**EDIT 1:** I also tried this and it failed:

```
wtf() {
  osascript - <<EOF
  tell application "iTerm"
      tell current terminal
          launch session "Railscasts"
          tell the last session
              write text "echo -ne \\\"\\e]1;$account\\a\\\""
          end tell
      end tell
  end tell
EOF
}
```

Error message:

```
163:164: syntax error: Expected end of line but found unknown token. (-2741)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppleScript doesn't support `'…'` for a string literal. You must use `"…"`, and escape the inner pair of `"…"` with `\`.

Also, it looks like shells reduce backslash sequences in heredocs (!!!), so you need to add more backslashes on the existing backslashes:

```
"echo -ne \"\\\\e]1;$account\\\\a\""
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it failed with a different error message...Please see my edit.

Comment: I think `"echo -ne \"\\e]1;$account\\a\""` is what you want.

Comment: @chepner I also tried that, but I get yet again a different error: `163:164: syntax error: Expected “"” but found unknown token. (-2741)`

Comment: @AzizLight: chepner's version is what I'd intended. There's some non-obvious behavior at work here (thanks, shells!), so I've posted the finished string literal in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also replace `<<EOF` with `<<'EOF'`:

```
<<'END'
\$` are not interpreted
END

<<END
\$` are interpreted
END
```

Or just use single quotes:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm"
    --
end tell'

X=999 osascript -e 'on run argv
    item 1 of argv + system attribute "X"
end run' 888
```

Comment: What's the significance of `888` at the end of the second example?

Comment: I just used 888 and 999 as examples on how to pass values to the script by adding an explicit run handler or by using environment variables.

Comment: Oh, I see—so when that script runs, `argv` will be `{888}` (or maybe `{"888"}`).